# iphone reload table data

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, reload

I am trying to update a list in a tableview controller. In viewWillAppear in that particular tableview controller, the tableView is setup with the code:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

I am trying to do this refresh from an other Class (DetailViewController), which refers to another view controller. 
In a method in DetailViewController I want to reload the data in JobsViewController, but can't do it. I can envision the below code working, but something is still missing. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

`[JobsViewController.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Are you sure the class variable you're calling this method on the same view you're displaying.
You need to have a reference in your view Controller in order to call this method, whether it's a reference through IB or maybe through code, using target delegates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you also change your data source? `reloadData` does only reload the cells. It doesn't take care of actually updating the underlying datasource. E.g. if you read data from an array in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, your have to change the array values befor calling reloadData.

Comment: yeah i guess thats the problem, I can reload that View Manually, and it doesn't do what I want anyway. Cheers for the tip.

Comment: Is there a way to reload the array or data source?